# The Syntax of Question words coming in the middle of an interrogative sentence

Tags: grammar, questions, wh-questions

Which one is correct?

> Does anybody know how can I create an account?

Vs

> Does anybody know how I can create an account?

Comment: Could you please explain what steps you have taken to find an answer yourself and why you are still unsure?

Comment: Your second example, without subject-auxiliary inversion, is the usual construction. The first, which has inversion, is possible, but it tends to only be heard in certain varieties of English (mainly in the USA).

Comment: The linked thread is not relevant here. The inversion is only possible in subordinate interrogatives in contexts of strong question-orientation, which is not the case with _Let's see how we can do this_, thus inversion is not permitted. But in this thread, where the example does meets that criteria, inversion is possible, though mainly for some speakers in the US, I believe.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you very much. I don't know why my question is closed.
So, basically both forms are correct. Am I right?

Comment: @Matin Please see my earlier comment.